# Keeping a custom form permanent

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm adding a custom form to one of my attributes fields, I want to create a drop-down menu where there is predecided values to choose from.

I'm going into the layer `property`>`Forms`>`Selecting the target field`, then I chose Widget type: `Value map`.

This works and I get a drop-down menu as I wanted. But this doesn't stay permanent, whenever I close and reload the field it goes back to Widget-type "text editing".

Is there a way I could keep my form permanent?

Using QGIS 3.4.5

Comment: You can't actually "close and re-load a field," so what are you actually talking about here? Closing and re-loading the attribute table? Or the QGIS project? Or the layer properties dialogue?